# Dynamic CRM Plugin Registration Tool returns unsecured or incorrectly secured fault

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I got an error while trying to register plugin using the plugin registration tool in the SDK. The problem comes out of nowhere since before today I always able to do plugin registration using the tool with ease.

The error message is this:

**Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:**

**An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party.**

**Inner Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.**

I've done my searching and already try some steps that commonly suggested which are:

1. Deleting the LiveDevice.xml file  under Users{username}\LiveDeviceID
2. Deleting the Connections.config file within the Plugin Registration Folder
3. Reboot the PC
4. Making sure the discovery url is correct (using: https://disco.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc)
5. Download and using the latest SDK.

My environment is Windows 8 64-bit.

However, it didn't resolved my issue.
Is there any steps or things that I've missed or may done wrongly?

Comment: your crm online uses windows LiveId or office365 authentication?

Comment: Have you tried shutting down, and restarting the tool?  Sometimes I've had issues where it has cached information locally that is incompatible with what is on the server.

Comment: @Daryl Yes already tried, but not helping :)

Comment: @AnthonySteven long shot: date & time of your pc is correct?

Comment: Thanks man, I finally got it working by following your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Guido comments about date & time of PC, I check the Dynamic CRM Online 2011 timezone, turns out it is set to (GMT +8 Krasnoyarsk), since I live in Singapore I changed it into (GMT +8 Singapore, Kuala Lumpur).

It is a long shot since the GMT is the same (+8), but I try it anyway and turns out it fixed the problem, I double check and change it again into Krasnoyarsk and again it's not working.

I'm not sure why this is causing it, since it is the same GMT, but for now I'll settle with this, maybe I'll raise a new topic for this later.

Thanks!