# Dynamic CRM Plugin Registration Tool, Same GMT Difference

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I raise this topic out of curiosity, related to my question in: [Dynamic CRM Plugin Registration Tool returns unsecured or incorrectly secured fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292179/dynamic-crm-plugin-registration-tool-returns-unsecured-or-incorrectly-secured-fa/17310204#17310204)

In short I got error of:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party.
>
> Inner Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred
>   when verifying security for the message.

Following suggestion to check the date and time in my PC, I decided to see whether my local time and Dynamic CRM 2011 Online server time is in sync. My local time is Singapore GMT (+8) and the Dynamic CRM 2011 Online server time is Krasnoyarsk GMT (+8).

Since it is the same GMT I assume both time are the same, however I tried to change the server time to Singapore, Kuala Lumpur GMT (+8) and suddenly the tool is working again.

I double checked by changing the timezone again to Krasnoyarsk and the same problem happened (I'm able to replicate it) so I'm certain this is the thing that caused my error.

I now wonder, why the same GMT Setting (Krasnoyarsk and Singapore is +8) can have a different effect? Or maybe my problem is caused by other entirely unrelated thing?

PS: I'm using the latest Dynamic CRM 2011 SDK.

Comment: The timezone bias might be effectively the same, but the timezones translate into a different timezone code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083233/timezonecode-to-timezoneinfo/17186899#17186899 for full list of timezone codes.

Comment: Is this a self-hosted CRM instance, or CRM Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different timezone code as suggest by Joris most likely have caused this behavior at the first place, this question is now closed.